# How do I use setters on mocked object?

Tags: java, mockito

Can a setter be used on a mocked object? I have a regular class that I have mocked, and I need to set some values for the mocked object.

Can I use setters on the mock object?

Comment: Yes, you can call a setter (if there is one). But what do you expect such a method call to do?

Comment: When I use a setter, the value is not getting set for the object. When I debug, it always comes as null.

Comment: If the object is being mocked you can't call it's methods unless you mock those too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mock data structures (like `List` and `Map`), and don't mock [POJOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object). Just use the real object. The idea behind mocking is to remove *behavior* from the equation, not data storage.

If the class is not a POJO, then you don't actually have to use a setter, you can just use `when` functionality for the getter, e.g.

```
when(mock.getSomeValue()).thenReturn(aRealValue);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you :)